# Unable ping own IP, but another Virtual Machine can ping it

Tags: networking, 16.04, vmware

I have a simple network here.
2 Virtual machine (ubuntu 16.04) (VMware) and connected with router in GNS3 
I only use IPv6 address. 
in VM2 I've installed kamailio sip server.

**vm1 ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:54:50:63  
          inet6 addr: 2001:1bcd:11::2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe54:5063/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42376 (42.3 KB)  TX bytes:12708 (12.7 KB)
```

**vm2 ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:8d:2c:56  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe8d:2c56/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:1bcd:1111::2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12952 (12.9 KB)  TX bytes:2742 (2.7 KB)
```

**router gns3**
sh ipv6 int br

```
FastEthernet1/0             [up/up]
  FE80::C801:1EFF:FE7C:1C
  2001:1BCD:11::1
FastEthernet1/1             [up/up]
  FE80::C801:1EFF:FE7C:1C
  2001:1BCD:1111::1
```

vm1 able ping to own IP, vm2 IP, router interface0/1 and router interface1/1 no trouble at all.

vm2 with IP address 2001:1BCD:1111::2 only able ping to router interface0/1 and router interface1/1.

the problem is vm2 (2001:1BCD:1111::2) unable ping to own IP address & unable ping to VM1 IP.

**VM2 PING OWN IP**

```
PING 2001:1BCD:1111::2(2001:1bcd:1111::2) 56 data bytes
From fe80::20c:29ff:fe8d:2c56 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fe80::20c:29ff:fe8d:2c56 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fe80::20c:29ff:fe8d:2c56 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
^C
--- 2001:1BCD:1111::2 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4102ms
```

**VM2 PING VM1**

```
PING 2001:1BCD:11::2(2001:1bcd:11::2) 56 data bytes
From fe80::c801:eff:fe7c:1d icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fe80::c801:eff:fe7c:1d icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fe80::c801:eff:fe7c:1d icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
^C
--- 2001:1BCD:11::2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2003ms
```

I don't know why my vm2 ping own ip and vm1 using link-local address instead using global address.

**EDIT 1** 
here is my ip -6 route show

```
2001:1bcd:1111::2 dev eth0  metric 1024  pref medium    
2001:1bcd:1111::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via 2001:1bcd:1111::1 dev eth0  metric 1024  pref medium
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address 2001:1BCD:1111::2
netmask 64
gateway 2001:1BCD:1111::1
```

Comment: Could router ping it?

Comment: @gryu router able ping to both vm. in vm2 i installed kamailio sip server, but i think installing kamailio not the problem ? hm

Answer (score 0):

Your vm2's ipv6 source is link-local. [It could not be routed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6).

> ```
> fe80::   10   link-local   Unroutable autoconfigured addresses used on a LAN, e.g. for DHCPv6
> ```

Maybe try to set `2001:1bcd:1111::1` as a default gateway for vm2:

```
sudo ip -6 route add 2001:1bcd:1111::1 dev eth0
```

Use `ip -6 route show` to see what is the default ipv6 route for your network interface

Configure router's interfaces to 2001:: adresses

Comment: i did try `2001:1bcd:1111::2` as a default gateway, but still got network unreachable. it actually makes vm2 unable ping to interface router gns3.<br/>

ip -6 route show<br/>
`2001:1bcd:1111::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via 2001:1bcd:1111::1 dev eth0  metric 1024  pref medium`